# Slide expand animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 5 layouts containing only the titles,which are aligned vertically as similar to list but not the list.I want to slide down each layout on click,to show the details,so that the next title should follow the current details.How can i implement this in android.
any help will be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for exapndable listView, these links might be helpful,

http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

```
 public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
// Sample data set. children[i] contains the children (String[]) for
// groups[i].
private String[] groups = { "Parent1", "Parent2",
    "Parent3" };
private String[][] children = { { "Child1" },{ "Child2" }, { "Child3" },{ "Child4" }, { "Child5" } };

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
    i = children[groupPosition].length;

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return i;
}

public TextView getGenericView() {
    // Layout parameters for the ExpandableListView
    AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 64);

    TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    // Center the text vertically
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
    textView.setTextColor(R.color.marcyred);
    // Set the text starting position
    textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
    return textView;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = getGenericView();
    textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
    return textView;
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups[groupPosition];
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.length;
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = getGenericView();
    textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
    return textView;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

}
```